# ConfigParser in R duplicates keys when writing

Tags: r, config

I am trying to use the ConfigParser library in R to write to an existing configuration file. The library is listed in CRAN along with the very short documentation. I created a dummy config file called test.ini with the following content:

```
[group]
why=1
are=2
you=3
broken=4
```

and then I use the following R script to write to the config file:

```
library(ConfigParser)

config <- ConfigParser$new() # Create a config parser
config$read("test.ini")

# create new keys to add to the config file
foo <- c(config$set("foo_key", "foo_value", "group")) 
bar <- c(config$set("bar_key", "bar_value", "group"))

config$write("test.ini")
```

When I run the R script the result is as expected:

```
[group]
bar_key=bar_value
foo_key=foo_value
why=1
are=2
you=3
broken=4
```

However, when I run it a second time I end up creating duplicate keys:

```
[group]
bar_key=bar_value
foo_key=foo_value
bar_key=bar_value
foo_key=foo_value
why=1
are=2
you=3
broken=4
```

This is obviously not desirable. The documentation is short and I didn't notice any options I might be overlooking. I also did not see any outstanding issues in the GitHub repository for the library. I can't imagine this being an oversight on the part of the person who created the library, so I must be missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I should have been more explicit about the second write. The second write may be legitimate as a result of the value associated to the key having changed. So my second run should have looked like so:

```
library(ConfigParser)

config <- ConfigParser$new() # Create a config parser
config$read("test.ini")

# create new keys to add to the config file
foo <- c(config$set("foo_key", "foo_changed", "group")) 
bar <- c(config$set("bar_key", "bar_changed", "group"))

config$write("test.ini")
```

And the results would then be:

```
[group]
bar_key=bar_changed
foo_key=foo_changed
bar_key=bar_value
foo_key=foo_value
why=1
are=2
you=3
broken=4
```

In every config file parser that I am aware of (GLib, python ConfigParser) the library will know enough to replace the existing value associated with the key to the new value, NOT simply duplicate the key in the configuration file. This is the problem.

Comment: If you run it n times, you are adding more entires again and again.  May be you need a `if/else` check or comment out the `config.write` line

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to have a `if/else` check

```
if(is.null(config$data[["group"]][["foo_key"]])) {
   # create new keys to add to the config file
   foo <- c(config$set("foo_key", "foo_value", "group")) 


    config$write("test.ini")
 }
```

The `config$data` returns a `list` with `key/value` pairs.  If the key is not present, the value will be `NULL`.  So, essentially we are asking to write only `if` the key is not present

-testing

```
# // initial case
config <- ConfigParser$new()
config$read("test.ini")
config$data
#$group
#$group$why
#[1] "1"

#$group$are
#[1] "2"

#$group$you
#[1] "3"

#$group$broken
#[1] "4"



config$data[["group"]][["foo_key"]]
#NULL
# // Now we add the new key
if(is.null(config$data[["group"]][["foo_key"]])) {
    # create new keys to add to the config file
    foo <- c(config$set("foo_key", "foo_value", "group")) 
     config$write("test.ini")
  }

# // Run the step again
if(is.null(config$data[["group"]][["foo_key"]])) {
    # create new keys to add to the config file
    foo <- c(config$set("foo_key", "foo_value", "group")) 
     config$write("test.ini")
  }

# // read it again
config$read("test.ini")
config$data
#$group
#$group$foo_key # added only the first time
#[1] "foo_value"

#$group$why
#[1] "1"

#$group$are
#[1] "2"

#$group$you
#[1] "3"

$group$broken
[1] "4"
```

Comment: The regular behavior for writes to configuration files is to replace the value associated with the key if the key already exists. I don't think this will do that?

Comment: @LeighK anyway this is working for me.   I showed the output as well